# Birt report issues

Tags: java, birt

I have upgraded the java 6 to java8 and the Birt report and chart are stop working so I would like to know that is the Birt is compatible with java and if Yes than how can i use to Birt report with Java 8

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Birt is compatible with java 8.use below maven 
       dependency to integrate with java.

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```